# Install superset on Windows 7 experienced through "build geo_hash" error

Tags: windows-7-x64, apache-superset, geohashing

I install Anacond with Python 3.7 on Win7 and then install superset but experience build geo_hash error. It said Microsft Visual C++ 14.0 required. However I did have installed it already, see the screenshot:
[image]

The error message shows:

*building '_geohash' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/*

Answer (score 0):

Install the geo-hash library using this command

```
pip install python-geohash
```